# getFreeDiskSpace() in Java 5

Tags: java

I am looking for a nice and easy way to display the free amount of space of a specific Hard Disk inside my Java Application.

I am quite surprised that this is only implemented in java 6 thanks to the method getFreeSpace() in the File class.

Unfortunately, we are using java 5 and don't want to change that for the moment.

Is there any way to do that in java 5 ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) provides a [FilesystemUtil.freespaceKb](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileSystemUtils.html) method, which works by issuing platform-specific process commands to the Runtime. Pretty ugly underneath, no doubt, but nice and easy on the surface.

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe this could help you :**

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileSystemUtils.html

> The current functions provided are:

```
* Get the free space on a drive
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Apache [org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileSystemUtils.html).